# Can't run 32-bit VB script from Python

Tags: vbscript, python-2.7

I am trying to run a VB script which is based on a 32-bit dll, as I have changed the default windows program to run this script (SysWoW64\cscript.exe), so I can run it simply by double clicking on it, now I want to run the same script within python 27 (32-bit) with the code below:

```
import os
os.chdir("C:\Users\OFFICE2\Desktop")
os.system("ResultSaver.vbs")
```

but it doesn't run! to be honest yesterday it was running perfectly but today it doesn't! I have restarted my PC several times but no changes happened!

can someone please help me, this is driving me crazy

I have windows 7 64-bit installed,

Comment: os.system("c:\blabla\SysWoW64\cscript.exe ResultSaver.vbs") ?

Comment: this was working yesterday, but it doesn't today, even I tried to run a batch file which call cscript and runs the VB script

Comment: does ResultSaver.vbs run from the command line?

Comment: yes it runs perfectly from windows command line,
also I tried to run the script with Python command line but I get this error: ResultSaver.vbs is not

Comment: recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Comment: did you try to run it as an argument to cscript.exe as in my comment?

Comment: yes I did, finally I found another way to run it, its written below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few days struggling with this problem finally I found a solution,

I made a batch file as:

```
C:\windows\SysWoW64\cscript.exe C:\Users\OFFICE2\Desktop\ResultSaver.vbs
```

then I converted my batch file to exe file with this website:

http://www.f2ko.de/programs.php?lang=en&pid=ob2e

and then ran the exe file with the below code:

```
import os
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
os.chdir("C:\Users\OFFICE2\Desktop")
Popen("myconvertedbatchfile.exe")
```

I am sure that there is an easier solution but for now this one works!